# WHERE name = 'cat' fails while `WHERE name LIKE '%cat` works on PostGres

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-like

I have a very simple query on Postgres that fails with a `WHERE =`, but works with `WHERE LIKE`. I have tags, some of them have a name containing the letters "cat":

```
pgdb=> SELECT * FROM tagging_tag WHERE tagging_tag.name LIKE '%cat%'
       ORDER BY tagging_tag.name ASC;

 id   |        name         | synonym_id
------+---------------------+------------
68496 | blackcat            |
    4 | cat                 |
28461 | catfight            |
```

It appears I have one tag named just "cat", but if I try to get it on its own, it fails:

```
pgdb=> SELECT * FROM tagging_tag WHERE tagging_tag.name = 'cat'
       ORDER BY tagging_tag.name ASC;
id | name | synonym_id
---+------+------------
(0 line)
```

But If I try with a partial `LIKE`, it works:

```
pgdb=> SELECT * FROM tagging_tag WHERE tagging_tag.name LIKE '%cat'
       ORDER BY tagging_tag.name ASC;
 id   |        name         | synonym_id
------+---------------------+------------
68496 | blackcat            |
    4 | cat                 |

pgdb=> SELECT * FROM tagging_tag WHERE tagging_tag.name LIKE 'cat%'
       ORDER BY tagging_tag.name ASC;
 id   |      name      | synonym_id
------+----------------+------------
    4 | cat            |
28461 | catfight       |
```

I tried to check the size, thinking of an invisible char but no chance :

```
pgdb=> SELECT char_length(name), * FROM tagging_tag WHERE tagging_tag.name LIKE 'cat%'
       ORDER BY "tagging_tag"."name" ASC;
char_length |  id   |      name      | synonym_id
------------+-------+----------------+------------
          3 |     4 | cat            |
          8 | 28461 | catfight       |
```

I made several tests, and it appears that some tag can be fetched with `=`, some can't, and I am unable to find any common denominators between them: number of letters vary, they are all ASCII lowercase, the ID are not grouped, etc.

Here is an EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tagging_tag WHERE tagging_tag.name = 'cat'
        ORDER BY tagging_tag.name ASC;
                                    QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index Scan using tagging_tag_name on tagging_tag  (cost=0.29..4.31 rows=1 width=19)
  Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'cat'::text)
(2 lignes)
```

Some context about the table:

```
pgdb=> \d tagging_tag
                                      Table « public.tagging_tag »
     Colonne   |         Type          |                        Modificateurs
    -----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------
    id         | integer               | non NULL Par défaut, nextval('...
    name       | character varying(50) | non NULL
    synonym_id | integer               |
    Index :
       "tagging_tag_id_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
       "tagging_tag_name" UNIQUE, btree (name)
       "tagging_tag_synonym_id" btree (synonym_id)
    Foreign key contraints :
       "tagging_tag_synonym_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (synonym_id) REFERENCES tagging_tag(id)
    Referenced by :
       TABLE "tagging_tag" CONSTRAINT "tagging_tag_synonym_id_fkey"
       FOREIGN KEY (synonym_id) REFERENCES tagging_tag(id)
```

Postgres version is 9.3.6.

Comment: What's the datatype of the `name` column? Is it `varchar` or `char`?

Comment: The Postgres version number would also be welcome.

Comment: The usual suspects are missing: table definition and Postgres version. Plus, the output of `EXPLAIN` and the definition of involved indexes, if any.

Comment: Updated the question. Do you need something else ?

Comment: Did you try smth like "select ... Where name = (select name ... Where id = 4) " ? Is it only an encoding problem?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker: I try both "=" and "IN" a subquery with a matching ID, but it doesn't return anything. I doubt it's an encoding problem, it's all ascii.

Comment: wow, if subquery does not work then smth is really broken. I'll think about it tomorrow ( it's midnight in Moscow)

Comment: Here too :) Sweet dreams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both tests with `name LIKE '%cat'` and `name LIKE 'cat%'` returned the same row and it includes string 'cat' only once (or does it?) it follows logically that `name = 'cat'` should return the same row as well.

Leading or trailing white space cannot explain this.

Remaining explanations include:

1. A misunderstanding and you tested with different databases / different tables, different `search_path` or something along this line.
2. A misunderstanding of a different kind: there is a line break in your string, which actUally looks like this:

   ```
   cat
   cat
   ```

   and you missed the second line?
3. A corrupt index. `EXPLAIN` output shows which index(es) might be used. Recreate involved indexes and see if that fixes the problem. Your question update shows it must be the index `tagging_tag_name`:

   ```
   REINDEX INDEX tagging_tag_name;
   ```

   The brute force alternative would be:

   ```
   VACUUM FULL tagging_tag;
   ```

   Rewrites the whole table and all indexes on it (taking an exclusive lock).

Comment: 1 can be discarded because we have 2 replicated db, and have the problem on both. 2 can be discarded by the test by char size test I put in the question. I'm trying the last one, but reindex seems to hang. I can't find a way to know if it's really slow or hanging. There are only 40k entries in this table, should it take seconds or minutes ?

Comment: shutting down posgres and restarting the reindex raised 3 errors stating duplicate rows. Removing these rows allowed to reindex. Now it works.

Comment: Accepted your answer :) Do you have  a suggestion on how to clean this mess in prod ? We can't restart postgres on the prod server.

Comment: Ah, done. It didn't need any rebooting on prod, reindexing did the trick. TY.